# How can I immediately replace the current toast with a second one without waiting for the current one to finish?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have many buttons. And on click of each of them I show a Toast. But while a toast loads and shows in the view, another button is clicked and the toast is not displayed until the one that is being displayed finishes.

So, I would like to sort out a way to detect if a toast is showing in the current context. Is there a way to know if a toast is being displayed such that I can cancel it and display a new one?

Comment: I think you are better off using the notifications framework to display your messages as you would be displaying multiple messages at the same time. If you use the toast or alert box solution you would need to manage positions/multiple pop ups , Notifications should help in simplifying your program.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can cache current `Toast` in Activity's variable, and then cancel it just before showing next toast. Here is an example:

```
Toast m_currentToast;

void showToast(String text)
{
    if(m_currentToast != null)
    {
        m_currentToast.cancel();
    }
    m_currentToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    m_currentToast.show();

}
```

---

Another way to instantly update `Toast` message:

```
void showToast(String text)
{
    if(m_currentToast == null)
    {   
        m_currentToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    m_currentToast.setText(text);
    m_currentToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    m_currentToast.show();
}
```

Comment: What about showing multiple toasts at the same time. Creating multiple instances and showing at distinct places in the view window ! Is this how it can be done ?

Comment: I think a popup might work better for you in this situation. Much more flexible with things like that.

Comment: I was looking for a way to cancel the existing toast if I show a new one.  Your first example doesn't work well for me, but the second version works great for my needs!

Comment: I suggest you put the setText(text) of your second answer in else block, so that the text is not set 2 times for newly created toast.

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you! if you combine it with a Singelton, you can use one toast overall the app and never get sick of still showing toasts!