# Android Create a TextView for every string in my Sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to display a new toast for every item in my cursor, how would I do this? I've searched SO, but can't find any relevant, useful answers. Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
 while(mNotesCursor.moveToNext()){ 
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  
    mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor.getColumnIndex("title")),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or just not getting the expected behavior?

Comment: just not getting the expected behavior

Comment: I haven't tested this before, but my guess would be that you can't show a new toast while another one is still showing. Take a look at  this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496725/showing-multiple-toast-at-the-same-time-problem

Comment: I tried that, but its still not working as expected.

Comment: You can show a toast while another is displaying. I believe they queue up. This means you should be careful, because if there are a lot of strings to be displayed, the user could be waiting for toasts to go away for hours. I like Smarth Jain's answer below.

Comment: The toasts were just for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toasting while iterating through the the cursor is not the best idea. Here's why:

You are using `LENGTH_LONG`, and the that means that a toast would last for approx 3 seconds.
Whereas your for loop would probably finish execution in a fraction of a second. So the toast would be displayed in order, but they would transition so slowly that it probably wouldn't make sense.

So i would suggest you to display the content in an alert dialog or the activity itself so the user would be able to make more sense out of the content.

EDIT:

I assume you are executing this on the main thread.

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findviewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    while(mNotesCursor.moveToNext()){
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setText(mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        root.addView(tv);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but its still not working as expected. My question is, how do I create a new TextView for every item in my cursor, and the TextViews content should be from the cursor, i.e the 2nd TextViews text should be the 2nd cursor items text.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to add textview to your view dynamically then here is how you can do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lineralayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

inside your activity class

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lineralayout1);
while(mNotesCursor.moveToNext()){ 
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(mNotesCursor.getString(mNotesCursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
l.addView(tv);
}
```