# How to put interval after a code is executed

Tags: android, time

how can i put a timer/timeout so that whenever a method is executed, there should be like 1 minute before it can be executed again. Example

```
if (A>B){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I dont want the toast to be spammed. So that if the condition is always satisfied, it will only show the toast every 1 minute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can record the time at which you last did that operation, and decline to do it again if not enough time has elapsed.

For example:

```
 private long lastRunTime = 0;
 void maybeDoSomething() {
     long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
     if ((now-lastRunTime) > (60 * 1000)) {
        //do something here
        lastRunTime = now;
     }
 }
```

System.currentTimeMillis() is a reasonable short-term time source, for longer timeouts you may want to investigate other clocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check against the current time.

Set a variable when the method is run and check against it when the condition is true

```
if (A>B && System.currentTimeMillis() > interal){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    interval = System.currentTimeMillis() + 6000;   // this should add 1 minute to the current time
}
```

make `interval` a `long` and a member variable...probably initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler in android to do some task after specific time...below code will do some task  after 5000ms. You can specify code for task inside run() method of Runnable Class.

```
    boolean methodRunnable = true;

    if(methodRunnale){
        // Run method 
        doSomeTask();
    }else{
       //Wait for 1 minute
    }

    void doSomeTask(){
        methodRunnable = false;

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           methodRunnable = true;
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 60*1000);
   }
```

Comment: To solve the posted requirement with this approach, you'd have to use your runnable to turn off a flag that was blocking the shouldn't-happen-too-often task.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is just to avoid "Toast Spamming", this can be avoided quite easily.
Please see [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676471/best-way-to-avoid-toast-accumulation-in-android/18676736#18676736) to [Best way to avoid Toast accumulation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676471/best-way-to-avoid-toast-accumulation-in-android). It also contains a complete code sample.