# Is it normal to show a single Toast multiple times on Android?

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm using `Toast` to show some information to the user, because I want to show the newest message without delay, regardless of the previous messages. I do it like this (learned from old projects):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Toast mToast;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    private void toast(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mToast.setText(message);
                mToast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That is, the single `Toast` object is reused and showed multiple times, whenever I need show a new message, I just `setText` and `show` it again. It seems working fine, but after I did some searching on Google, I found most people will do it like this:

```
    private void toast(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mToast.cancel();
                mToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Which `cancel`s the previous Toast and then makes a new one by `Toast.makeText`.

Are there any differences? Which one should I prefer?

Comment: In general its better to cancel a toast before you show a new one. the reason is if you are showing multiple toasts in a short period of time, it can be confusing for the user if they are seeing a toast that has nothing to do with the action they just performed

Comment: Yes, but the two methods are just identical to users.

Comment: Yes, but if you need to show a toast immediately, its better to cancel the toast. Its more of a problem if you are using a LENGTH_LONG toast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Multiple Toast Overlaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922516/how-to-prevent-multiple-toast-overlaps)

Comment: Which one you should prefer definitely only depends on what you want. Do you want the toasts stacked or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the current Toast in the Activity's variable, and then cancel it just before showing the next toast. Here is an example:

Toast m_currentToast;

```
void showToast(String text)
{
    if(m_currentToast != null)
    {
        m_currentToast.cancel();
    }
    m_currentToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    m_currentToast.show();

}
```

Another way to instantly update the Toast message:

```
void showToast(String text)
{
    if(m_currentToast == null)
    {
        m_currentToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    m_currentToast.setText(text);
    m_currentToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    m_currentToast.show();
}
```

Reference: *[How can I immediately replace the current toast with a second one without waiting for the current one to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496725/showing-multiple-toast-at-the-same-time-problem)*

Answer (score 0):

You should try to code something like this to avoid visibility of multiple toasts at a time.

```
 private void toast(final String message) {
 try{ mToast.getView().isShown();     // True if visible
        mToast.setText(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {         // Invisible if exception
        mToast = Toast.makeText(theContext, message, toastDuration);
        }
    mToast.show();  // Finally display it
}
```

Code help me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925156/how-to-avoid-a-toast-if-theres-one-toast-already-being-shown).

Comment: sorry I did see that post, but I want figure out the underlying differences.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to create a function for your Toast *and* use that function as per your requirements.

Your solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925156/how-to-avoid-a-toast-if-theres-one-toast-already-being-shown).

Answer (score 0):

It is better use cancel() before showing the same toast.
Better close the lifecycle of the toast to prevent a bug.

This method closes the view if it's showing, or doesn't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally the view will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.